# Calling existing apache commands in Symfony Console

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-console

I'm trying to build a command line application that will assist in setting up a new local development environment for me. It just creates a few files to link up the Virtual Host stuff. Nothing I'm not already doing manually.

I am just not sure how to do the restarting apache part. This is my main file;

```
class SetupEnvironment extends Command
{
    public function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('new')
            ->setDescription('Set up a new development environment.')
            ->addArgument('name', InputArgument::REQUIRED, "Project or application name")
            ->addOption('sub_folder', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'Name of public folder', '');
    }

    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        // make directory for development environment - done

        // create conf file and contents - done

        // create sym-link - done

        // add to pow - done

        // restart apache and powder up - not done
```

I have only just started learning Symfony Console/Filesystem today so not really sure the proper way to call commands that already exist like `sudo apachectl restart` and then `powder up`

Comment: Can you please make your question more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Youn can use the [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) command:

```
exec('sudo apachectl restart');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `exec()` commands which runs command line arguments via a php code. http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php